# listening to variable while transmitting video

Tags: video-streaming, gstreamer

I have main function and thread,

the main function get commands from client (works fine)
and the thread that transmits video fluently to the client (works fine)

I need that the main function will pass th command to the thread with transmitting video, the thread read that command and react accordingly- play\ pause.

now, after  "gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);"
the thread will start transmitting the video:

```
void *thread_function(void * variable)
{
   ...
   ...
   ...
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
  ....
  ....
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
```

}

how do I make the thread to listen to some command_variable from the main while its transmitting video?
is the thread "stuck" on the " gst_element_set_state" (like while(1)) ?
the thread suppose to get that command_variable from the main function and react accordingly.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use **socket programming** to create a `udp` or `tcp` socket on a port number which is different from the port number on which you handle your video or any other media for that matter.On this port you should wait for incoming messages. You can add authentication procedure to your message receiving process.
According to the message which is received on the port, you can take additional actions like

```
GST_STATE (pipeline) == GST_STATE_PAUSED
```

or any other action that you would like to do.

[here](http://www.binarytides.com/programming-udp-sockets-c-linux/) you can find some examples on how to create sockets and do the **LISTENING**  action.